# .service terminated directories treated as OSX specific/reserved entities

Tags: eclipse, macos, eclipse-rcp

During my EclipseRCP development I often end up having Eclipse plugin project directory terminating with `.service`, as result of the [Reverse-DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse-DNS) naming convention.

Osx 10.7 default behavior is to treat these directory as "kind Service", which makes them greyed out in Finder.

Now, when I try to import one of these existing project in my workspace, I am unable to do so as I cannot choose these ".service" terminated directory from the Eclipse import wizard.

I tried to "Get Info" them in Finder, to see if I could somehow unregister this reserved extension, without luck.

How can I get around this unfortunate circumstance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a workaround:

with the wizard, choose the parent directory, making sure it's not itself an Eclipse project root (does not contain .project file).

Existing projects in the subfolders should show up for selection, including the .service one.